# ng bootstrap typeahead not working with angular reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

Here is my component file

```
import {NgbTypeahead} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { map, switchMap, finalize, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject, merge } from 'rxjs';

const states = [.....]

// inside class
@ViewChild('instance', {static: true}) instance: NgbTypeahead;
focus$ = new Subject<string>();
click$ = new Subject<string>();

search = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(debounceTime(200), distinctUntilChanged());
const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$.pipe(filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()));
const inputFocus$ = this.focus$;

return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
  map(term => (term === '' ? states
    : states.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10))
);
}
```

And in my html i use reactive form binding

```
<input
    id="typeahead-focus"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    formControlName="userAssigned" 
    [ngbTypeahead]="search"
    (focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value)"
    (click)="click$.next($event.target.value)"
    #instance="ngbTypeahead"
    />
```

also initialized my form inside `ngOnInit()` like this

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  userAssigned: ['', Validators.required],
});
```

When i run this code and click on the input, i am getting the result in pop but getting this error. Also unable to get result when i clear the first result.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: has you enclosed in a `<div [formGroup]="form">`?, what version of ng-bootstrap (me "^5.1.1")?, it's working for me, see a stackblitz forked https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jclc4z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @Eliseo yes i have it `<div [formGroup]="form">`. Versions i am using (Angular 8.1.2, ng-bootstrap 5.1.1, bootsctrap css 4.3.1). I followed your stackblitz but couldn't find what i am doing wrong.

Comment: @Eliseo i also found that `(focus)` has no issue with code. only when i `(click)` input the error comes. I forked your stackblitz and changed to versions i am using. It works fine there but not in my code. I have no idea what i did wrong.

Comment: see my answer, it's only add `this.instance` to the filter. (I updated the stackblitz too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that when search function is declared, "instance is undefined". This happens e.g. if we has some like

```
<div *ngIf="form" [formGroup]="form">
...
</div>
```

The solution is add `this.instance` in the filter, becomes like `this.instance && !this.instance.isPopupOpen`

So, the completed function search is

```
    search = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(debounceTime(200), distinctUntilChanged());
    const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$.pipe(filter(() => 
      this.instance && !this.instance.isPopupOpen())); //<---HERE
    const inputFocus$ = this.focus$;

    return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
      map(term => (term === '' ? states
        : states.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10))
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right. Now its working with all validation.